# How can I reload video driver after black screen?

Tags: intel-graphics, gpu-driver

I have intel  i915 graphic driver. Sometimes I get black screen, I have a shortcut for `sudo service lightdm restart` but it doesn't fix black screen problem. How can I reload graphic driver?

EDIT: It happens during heavy load of CPU, once it happened while scrolling chromium page.

Output of xrandr:

```
 xrandr
 Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1280 x 800, maximum 32767 x 32767
 LVDS1 connected 1280x800+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 331mm x 207mm
    1280x800       60.0*+
    1024x768       60.0  
    800x600        60.3     56.2  
    640x480        59.9  
 VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
 TV1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
 VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

EDIT2:
Though I accepted the below answer which was posted by `terdon` , after I tested it many times I must note that it doesn't work.

How can I reload video driver when I get black screen?

Comment: When does this black screen happen? Is it after the computer has gone to sleep mode? I have a similar issue and have fixed it by creating a shortcut that runs `xrandr` to fix my resolution. Please  [edit] your post and show the output of `xrandr`. I should be able to give you the right command.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this will solve your issue, you might have a different problem to mine. In my case, the black screen happens when the computer has been left alone for a while and the screen has turned off. While moving the mouse or pressing a key wakes it up, the screen remains black.

My workaround is to run an `xrandr` command that sets up my screen again. In your case, the command would be:

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --auto
```

If that does not set up the correct resolution, use this one instead:

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --mode 1280x800
```

However, that's hard to type on a black screen. So, make a little script that runs this command:

```
echo -e '#!/bin/bash\nxrandr --output LVDS1 --mode 1280x800` > ~/bin/fix_screen.sh
```

The command above will create a file in your `$HOME/bin` directory (if the directory does not exist, create it with `mkdir ~/bin`) called `fix_screen`. Now, make the script executable:

```
chmod +x ~/bin/fix_screen
```

Finally, assign a shortcut to it. Open the Settings dialog:

[image]

Then, go to Keyboard => Shortcuts => Custom Shirrtcuts and click on the <kbd>+</kbd> sign:

[image]

And then enter this:

[image]

Finally, choose a shortcut for it. Just click on `Disabled` and then type the shortcut you want:

[image]

Now, the next time you have this black screen issue, just use the keyboard shortcut and everything should be fine.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I ll try your method and let you know.

Comment: Though I accepted the above answer, after I tested it many times I must note that it doesn't work.

Comment: @kenn please edit your question and explain exactly how it doesn't work. I should be able to help you work it out. Please show me the exact script you used, clarify whether it is executable and whether it runs correctly when run manually.

Comment: I made a script like `xrandr --auto --output LVDS1 --mode 1024x768` I tested the script, it works ok, but when I get black screen, it's not working, I tried it a few times because `facebook/lookback` video gives me black screen.